# How to handle this kind of c++ error in python

Tags: python, c++, sql, bulk, pymssql

I have a problam in string of code:

```
self.db.bulk_insert('input', lines, columns_numbers = (2,3))
```

where `db` is my wrap for pymssql. Here is the method of that class:

```
def bulk_insert(self, table_name:str, dataset:Sequence, columns_numbers:Sequence=None):
    self._connection.bulk_copy(table_name, dataset, columns_numbers)
```

where `_connection` is just pymssql connection.

When I`am running it the data are inserting, but in console appears

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

and code not going further.

Table and data I am inserting, quite simple:

```
CREATE TABLE input (
  id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ipn VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  info_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES info(id),
  fetched BIT DEFAULT 0,
  inserted DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Element of `lines` is looking like: `('1234567890', Decimal('1'))`

Why its happening and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be some sort of incompatibility between libraries. How did you build pymssql?

Comment: I installed it with pip.
pymssql was version 2.2.3. I made an update. Now it is 2.2.5 and nothing changed ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue.
Befor that bulk_insert i made db request to get that id to insert. In table it `int`, but returns as `Decimal('1')` as i metioned in my question.

So, the problem was in data type I am inserting (decimal), because table type is int.